# Inviting Facebook friends not using the app without Canvas implementation

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

My question is simple :

I am developing an android game and I wish to implement a feature for signed in users(through fb) to invite those friends who are not signed into my app. The invitable friends api only workd if you have a canvas implementation of your game. Is there any straight way of implementing this.

My preference is to be able to query the list of friends through api and show them in my game itself(not any sdk dialog)

Comment: How to invite people are described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important link for you is already in the comments: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Main point: You can´t query the list of friends without `invitable_friends`, and `invitable_friends` can only be used in games on canvas. That´s how it is and there is no way around this.

This is what you can do, and only this:

> You may use the Message Dialog on iOS and Android, or the Send Dialog on Web. These products let a person send a message directly to their friends containing a link to your app